# Is there a way to call a function from a different python file when using signals and slots in PyQT5?

Tags: python, function, import, pyqt5

I am building software using PyQT5 and I am trying to keep my main application file separate from my functions. When clicked, some widgets call certain functions. I would like to store these functions in a different python file. When imported, I get an error.

I am importing the function using this line of code:

```
from Open import OpenFile
```

I am trying to use OpenFile in another function :

```
def experiment(self):
     BSel = QPushButton("Select File",self.window)
            self.window.tab1.layout.addWidget(BSel)
            BSel.clicked.connect(self.OpenFile)
```

The function called OpenFile is saved in Open.py. The function is:

```
def OpenFile(self):
    global fileName
    options = QFileDialog.Options()
    options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
    fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self.window, "Import File", "",
                                                  "All Files (*);;Data Files (*.asc);;Excel Files (*.csv)", options=options)
    print(fileName)
```

How can I call the function OpenFile, saved in a separate python file, when QBushButton is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `OpenFile` uses the `self` argument, but it's also an anonymous function (it's not a member of a class); the result is that `self` will be the argument given by the signals that calls it.

The `clicked` signal always have a `checked` argument (which is usually `False` for normal buttons), so the `self` within the `OpenFile` function will be that bool value, which will cause an exception since that value doesn't have any `window` attribute.

So, you cannot directly connect to it. You should either use a lambda or call another function that actually calls `OpenFile`. Since you'll probably need the returned file name, lambda is not the right choice here.

main.py

```
class SomeWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.openFile)

    def openFile(self):
        fileName = OpenFile(self)
```

Open.py

```
def OpenFile(parent):
    options = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.Options()
    options |= QtWidgets.QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
    fileName, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
        parent.window(), 
        "Import File", "", 
        "All Files (*);;Data Files (*.asc);;Excel Files (*.csv)", 
        options=options)
    return fileName
```

In case you were hoping that by using `global fileName` in `Open.py` you would end up "setting" `fileName` in your main script, you're off track.

Globals in Python are *global to the module*: there's no way to set a global on a script *from* an imported module/script.

Remember that there are very few cases for which using globals is the right choice, and most of the times if you're using it you're probably doing it for the wrong reason.